# Trying to print the doctype declaration

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = urlopen("http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/live/bbcone?area=london")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
version = bsObj.find(string = re.compile('DOCTYPE html'))

if version in bsObj:
    print("Yes")
else:
    print("No")
```

I know the doctype declaration for "http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/live/bbcone?area=london" is html 5 (!DOCTYPE html) but when I run this script the output is "No". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE>` isn't an HTML tag but a declaration and `find()` doesn't work with the full text of those. apparently. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499358/get-document-doctype-with-beautifulsoup for some ideas.

Comment: @kindall -- This question looks to me like it should be a dupe of that one though I hesitate to mark it since you didn't ;-) ...

Comment: I feel like this question isn't a strict dupe because it's asking what the problem is with `.find()` rather than how to get the doctype.

Answer (score 0):

Doctype is an instruction to the browser so find and find_all won't find it normally because it is not an html tag.

Other than that your regex won't work because the `string` value in BS is only `html` rather than `DOCTYPE html`.

You can use the link that user `kindall` mentioned or use it this way:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Doctype

html = requests.get("http://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/live/bbcone?area=london")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "html.parser")
version = soup.find_all(string="html")
DOCTYPE = next(item for item in version if isinstance(item, Doctype))

print (DOCTYPE)
```

Which will print:

> html