# Is DOCTYPE the parent of HTML tag?

Tags: python, html, dom

The below code is giving me output as HTML. I am confused with DOCTYPE. What's the parent of the HTML tag here? Is it DOCTYPE?

```
html = list(soup.children)[1]
print(html)
```

Comment: please read and follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) thanks

Comment: `<!DOCTYPE>` is a *preamble*, it is not part of the HTML document proper.

Answer (score 0):

DOCTYPE is a top-level declaration, not a parent of the <html> element.

In Beautiful Soup [the `BeautifulSoup` object you get from the parser is the container for both the DOCTYPE and the root HTML element](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children).

See also [Get document DOCTYPE with BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499358/get-document-doctype-with-beautifulsoup)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly. Think of the <!DOCTYPE> declaration as more of a sibling to the  tag rather than a parent. It's like the first thing you see when you open a webpage, setting the tone for the HTML structure, but it doesn't directly enclose the  tag like a parent would.