# How do I read all html-files in a directory recursively?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I am trying to get all html-files Doctype printed to a txt-file. I have no experience in Python, so bear with me a bit. :)

Final script is supposed to delete elements from the html-file depending on the html-version given in the Doctype set in the html-file. I've attempted to list files in PHP as well, and it works to some extent. I think Python is a better choice for this task.

The script below is what I've got right now, but I cant figure out how to write a "for each" to get the Doctype of every html-file in the arkivet folder recursively. I currently only prints the filename and extension, and I don't know how to get the path to it, or how to utilize BeautifulSoup to edit and get info out of the files.

```
import fnmatch
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
from bs4 import Doctype

files = ['*.html']
matches = []

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("arkivet"):
    for extensions in files:
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, extensions):
            matches.append(os.path.join(root, filename))
            print(filename)
```

*matches* is an array, but I am not sure how to handle it properly in Python. I would like to print the foldernames, filenames with extension and it's doctype into a text-file in root.

Script runs in CLI on a local Vagrant Debian server with Python 3.5 (Python 2.x present too). All files and folders exist in folder called arkivet (archive) under servers public root.

Any help appreciated! I'm stuck here :)

Comment: Literally no reason to tag "PHP" since it has nothing to do with PHP at all.

Comment: Can you trace back your full error ?

Comment: @VikasDamodar This scripts has no error. It spits out the filenames and extensions only, as I described in the text. :) Only I can't figure out how to do the rest.

Comment: So basically you want to read all the html files in a directory ?

Comment: Of course it only "prints" the filenames, that's the only thing you print. The files path are in your `matches` list (nb: it's a `list` not an `array` - those are distinct types in Python). wrt/ the html version you'll have to parse the files (using a real html parser - beautifulsoup is probably your best bet here -, a regexp-based is not going to be reliable or will require way to much debugging so don't reinvent the proverbial squared wheel).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes, thank you for pointing that out. I did try a regexp-based function in PHP, but as you say, it's not 100%. I need Python to extract/read all the doctypes of my html-files in the directory and list them in a text-file. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you did not mark any of the answers solutions, I'm guessing you never quite got you answer. Here's a chunk of code that recursively searches for files, prints the full filepath, and shows the Doctype string in the html file if it exists.

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Doctype

directory = '/home/brian/Code/sof'
for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith('.html'):
            fname = os.path.join(root, filename)
            print('Filename: {}'.format(fname))
            with open(fname) as handle:
                soup = BeautifulSoup(handle.read(), 'html.parser')
                for item in soup.contents:
                    if isinstance(item, Doctype):
                        print('Doctype: {}'.format(item))
                        break
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. This snippet only works to some extent, there seems to be a bunch of UnicodeDecodeError's. Everything from invalid start bytes, to invalid continuationbyte. 

I'll mark your answer as the correct one. Maybe Python is not so good for this task after all.

Comment: Tried it with Python 2.7, and it then works fine. However It can't read all my html-files doctypes, I'll have to look into those files manually and see what might cause it. Maybe Python 2.7 just skips the files that Python3 halts on.

Answer (score 2):

Vikas's answer is probably what you are asking for, but in case he interpreted the question incorrectly, it's worth it to know that you have access to all three of those variables as you're looping through, root, dirnames, and filenames. You are currently printing just the basefile name:

```
print(filename)
```

It is also possible to print the full path instead:

```
print(os.path.join(root, filename))
```

Vikas solved the lack of directory name by using a different function (os.listdir), but I think that will lose the ability to recurse.

A combination of os.walk as you posted, and reading the interior of the file with open as Vikas posted is perhaps what you are going for?

Comment: Correct, I am only printing filename. Printing the matches shows a whole bunch of filenames and their path in list, not array (as earlier stated in comments). I am however also trying to get the doctype into this list. Path + Filename + doctype in a text-file is what I am trying to do. 

Later on I would like to use the doctype to do a switch/case to edit files depending on what doctype the file have, but that specific feature is for a later question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read all the html files in a particular directory you can try this one :

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

directory ='/Users/xxxxx/Documents/sample/'
for filename in os.listdir(directory):
     if filename.endswith('.html'):
         fname = os.path.join(directory,filename)
         with open(fname, 'r') as f:
             soup = BeautifulSoup(f.read(),'html.parser')
             # parse the html as you wish
```

Comment: Yes, BeautifulSoup is useful. I am however trying to utilize the Doctype module ti identify the doctype of every html-file. BeautifulSoup does not read the doctype-element unfortunately. I'm guessing that I soup will contain the entire html-file, but BS is unable to identify the specific element holding doctype. :)

Comment: Why use `os.listdir()` in your example when the OP explicitely says he has to do a recursive search and alread_ uses the right function (`os.walk`) for this ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers So, how would you do this? I am using os.walk(), but I also need the doctype for each html-document.

Comment: @ChristerJohansson And ? Why would it make any difference wrt/ parsing the file ? As long as you have the full file path (which you already have with the code you posted, in your `matches` list), the way you got that past is irrelevant.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers The difference is that I don't understand, so if you please could show me a code example I would appreciate it very much. Also, BeautifulSoup does not read doctype only the other elements of html. :)

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers if the OP can only do with `os.walk()` then the some of the lines of code can be changed to `for root, directory, filename in os.walk("arkivet"):` instead of  `for filename in os.listdir(directory):`

Comment: @VikasDamodar given the above comment I think you assume too much about the OP's skills...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers sorry if you are mistaken. I just meant that if he is looking for the answers  in that way(`os.walk()`) then he can change it to like i mentioned

Comment: @ChristerJohansson wrt/ doctype the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499358/get-document-doctype-with-beautifulsoup

Comment: @VikasDamodar _I_ am not "mistaken" - I just wondered why you used `os.listdir` instead of `os.walk` when the OP already used the later, and mentionned that it obviously confuses the OP indeed.

Comment: Problem with this is that Python3 returns a error. AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'endswith'. I changed filename to name, but still same error.