# How do I distinguish between XML and HTML programmatically in Python?

Tags: python, html, xml, lxml

I am sending an http request and get an http response, but I'd like to be able to extract the body of the response and know whether it contains XML or HTML.

Ideally, this method should work even if the content type isn't clear in the response (ie. it should work for websites where content type isn't necessarily specified).

Currently, I'm using lxml to parse the html/xml, but don't know at parse time whether I'm dealing with HTML or XML.

Answer (score 0):

You can check `content-type` header to know which type of response you got:

```
import requests

respond = requests.get(URL)
file_type = respond.headers['content-type']

print(file_type)

>>>'text/html; charset=utf-8'
```

You can also do

```
print(file_type.split(';')[0].split('/')[1])
```

to get `"html"` or `"xml"` as output

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you would like to do it, and I'm sure there is a better way to do it. But...

The difference beween xml and html is the declaration, HTML must start with `<!DOCTYPE HTML>`, and XML with `<?xml version="1.0>`

Example of XML

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<address>
<name> Krishna Rungta</name> 
<contact>9898613050</contact>
<email>krishnaguru99@gmail.com </email>
<birthdate>1985-09-27</birthdate>
</address>
```

Example of HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Page title </title> </head>
<body>
<hl> First Heading</hl> <p> First paragraph.</p> </body>
</html>
```

If I were you, I would use BeautifulSoup to select DOCTYPE, and if you can't find/select it means it is XML. You can see how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499358/get-document-doctype-with-beautifulsoup).

If this doesn't answer your question try reading [this](https://www.guru99.com/xml-vs-html-difference.html) or try using this [library](https://www.guru99.com/xml-vs-html-difference.html)